# How can I write a single instruction to switch two values into a variable every time the instruction is being executed?

Tags: c, functional-programming, generic-programming

I'd like to write a single instruction to switch two values into a variable at every instruction execution; this is the generic case: having two values `x1, x2` and `i` initialized to `x1` or `x2`, switch i value between `x1` and `x2` at every instruction execution, i.e. `i= x1, x2, x1 ...;` or, if i is initialized to x2, `i = x2, x1, x2, ...;`

E.g. to switch between 0 and 1: `i= 3 % (i+2);`

How can I write the generic `x1, x2` case instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```
 i=(x1+x2)-i
```

Comment: Abs should be removed. Thats exactly one instruction, because x1 + x2 is constant.

Comment: Yeah "x1+x2" will definitely going to be greater than "i" and no room for negative result. So abs should be removed.

Comment: @blue Yeah. But you knwo *, / and % are very costly operation when you are looking for atomic instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Bit operations are very fast, so if it's an integer variable,

```
type z = x1 ^ x2, i = x1;
// do something
while(...) {
    i ^= z;
    // ...
}
```

an XOR is a fast solution.

The trick behind it is that XOR is associative and commutative, and `x ^ x == 0` for all `x` as well as `0 ^ x == x`.

So when `i == x1`,

```
i ^= z ~> i = x1 ^ (x1 ^ x2) ~> i = (x1 ^ x1) ^ x2 ~> i = 0 ^ x2 ~> i = x2
```

and when `i == x2`, the `x2`s in `x2 ^ (x1 ^ x2)` cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something as simple as

```
i = (i==x1)?x2:x1;
```

Will do the trick

Comment: I believe that alternating value without a test, for any two arbitrary values, is not possible. You may use xor operation to alternate between values without test, but you have to restrict yourself to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Through a lot of discussion i finally realized what you need:)

Here is a code sample of my solution:

```
#define x1 7
#define x2 11

int main(void )

{
  int a = 0;
  int val = x1;
  int xorFactor = x1^x2;

  printf("\n");
  for (a=0; a<10; a++) {
    val = val^xorFactor;
    printf("%d: %d\n", a, val);
  }

  return 0;
}
```